# A better way to loop through 2 Dataframes

Tags: python

I have 2 Dataframes. i am trying to find corresponding row values based on filter values. At the end, i want to add some columns in df2 to df1. The problem with the example below is that it is nor efficient when dealing with large dataset.

```
selected_rows = pd.Dataframe()
         for i, rowi in df1.iterrows():
              for j, rowj in df2.iterrows():
                if (rowi['Customer'] == rowj['Customer']) & (rowi['CaseID'] == rowj['CaseID']):
                    rowi['Resolution'] = rowj['Resolution']
                    rowi['Diagnostic'] = rowj['Diagnostic']
                    selected_rows = selected_rows.append(rowi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me: [link](https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc).
I use an approach like this instead of using `iterrows()`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4]
], columns=['Customer', 'CaseID', 'Resolution', 'Diagnostic'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1.1, 1.2, 4.3, 4.4],
    [2.1, 2.2, 5.3, 5.4],
    [6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4]
], columns=['Customer', 'CaseID', 'Resolution', 'Diagnostic'])

for i in df1.index:
    customer_i = df1._get_value(i, 'Customer')
    CaseID_i = df1._get_value(i, 'CaseID')
    for j in df2.index:
        customer_j = df2._get_value(j, 'Customer')
        CaseID_j = df2._get_value(j, 'CaseID')

        if customer_i == customer_j and CaseID_i == CaseID_j:
            df1['Resolution'][i] = df2._get_value(j, 'Resolution')
            df1['Diagnostic'][i] = df2._get_value(j, 'Diagnostic')
            break

print(df1)
```

which seems to be faster, but I think there are multiple approaches to get even faster.

Comment: Also if each `Customer` - `CaseID` combination is unique, you could use a `break` statement inside your `if` statement to stop iterating over the rest of `df2`.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific and included the break statement.

Comment: Thank you for for response @steTATO Do you know if there is a way to avoid the loop

Comment: The part  df1['Resolution'][i] = df2._get_value(j, 'Resolution')
             df1['Diagnostic'][i] = df2._get_value(j, 'Diagnostic')  gives an error for me. This part is suppose to create the column value of df2 in df1. but i get the exception Resolution

Comment: If you run just my code it should work. If you implemented it in your code, I don't know what the error might be. Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know an approach without loop. There might be some in-built pandas functions to compare dataframes? But pretty sure they also use loops inside. In general working with numpy instead of pandas might be faster as well. Other than that if you have GB big files, you might wanna sort/split them. For example one df only holds lines with case ids starting with 1 and so on...

Comment: If you are still looking for other solutions. The inbuild pandas function is `pd.merge`. Retry my code, but replace the looping part with `df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Customer', 'CaseID'], suffixes=['_1', '_2'])`. I don't think it is faster, but it is only one line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So far, your method is faster than my initial code and it helps cover what I intended to do.